# Ajax Error : Not return database Value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a problem with my ajax php coding.
The problem is when the user enter their password to login ,the live checking function output only shown blank in select box below, not the data from database.
Below is my code:

Login.php

```
username:<input type="text" class="name" id="uname" placeholder="enter your username here"><br>
password:<input type="password" class="pass" id="pword" placeholder="password here"><br>
<div id="txt">
   responsibility:<select id="opti">
        <option value=""> Select your responsibility</option>
</select><br></div>


<script>
function showUser(str) {
   if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST","dblogin.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
   }
}
document.getElementById('pword').addEventListener("keyup", function(str) {
    showUser(str);
}, false);
</script>
```

Dblogin.php

```
<?
$q=intval($_POST["pword"]);

require ("config.php");
$link=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

$query="select responsibility from testing where password = '".$q."'";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
    if($result){
?>
<form>
responsibility:<select id="opti">
<?
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    echo"<option value='$row[1]'>$row[1]</option>";
?>
</select>
<input type=submit value ="submit">
<?
}
else
{
?>
Error:No Data Found
<?
}
?>
```

config.php

```
<?
   $host="localhost";
   $db="logindb"
   $user="root"
   $pass="";
?>
```

the ajax function is work, but the database data not shown. Can anybody tell me what wrong with my coding.

Comment: `xmlhttp.send();` - you're not sending any post data - you could change your method to GET, and `$q=intval($_GET["q"]);`